# Program uses files

Tags: java, file, class

im beginner in java and i found an example that input from txt files.

```
public class MyCollection {

    private String mInputFilePath = null;
    private String mOutputFilePath = null;
    private ArrayList<Document> mDocuments = null;
    private HashMap<String, Integer> mDocumentFrequencies = null;

    public MyCollection(String inputFile, String outputFile) {
        mInputFilePath = inputFile;
        mOutputFilePath = outputFile;
        mDocuments = new ArrayList<Document>();
        mDocumentFrequencies = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    }

    public void process(){
        BufferedReader inputBufferedReader = null;
        BufferedWriter outputBufferedWriter = null;
        try {
            inputBufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(mInputFilePath)));
            outputBufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File(mOutputFilePath)));
        }
```

I cant understand this code here:

```
inputBufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(mInputFilePath)));
outputBufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(newFile(mOutputFilePath)));
```

how can i write this to lines more analytical?

Comment: Question is really not clear, can you elaborate ?

Comment: What do you mean by "analytical"?

Comment: i think that these two lines do things that i can write in more lines to be understandable. First of all i must create the inputBufferedReader, secondly i must create the FileReader and etc

Comment: maybe this helps you understand it a bit more: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern

Answer (score 1):

this `inputBufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(mInputFilePath)));`

is the same as

```
File file = new File(mInputFilePath);
FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);

inputBufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fr);
```

There is no advantage or disadvantage for the compiler as to which way to use

Comment: im making the same for the second line but im getting error. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Some codes are put in each other without needing for creating an instance.

```
BufferedReader inputBufferedReader = null;

BufferedWriter outputBufferedWriter = null;


File fi = new File(mInputFilePath);

FileReader fri = new FileReader(fi);

inputBufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fri);

File fo = new File(mOutputFilePath);

FileReader fro = new FileReader(fro);

outputBufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fro);
```

Comment: But now when im compilinig this program im getting this message:
cannot find symbol
symbol  : constructor BufferedWriter(java.io.File)
location: class java.io.BufferedWriter
   outputBufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fOutput);